# How can I use prior version recovery mode?

Tags: drivers

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 (from 11.10) this morning.  After the installation succeeded, the computer restarted and since then I have not been able to use my keyboard or mouse (once I get to the graphical UI login screen).

Is it possible to rollback the installation to its previous state?  I am hoping to avoid a fresh install as I have installed a bunch of dev tools and its quite painful to have to re-install everything

[EDIT] : Title changed.  The previous title was "How to rollback Ubuntu installation to 64bit 11.10" as installing Ubuntu 12.04 over 11.10 ended up making my computer unusable

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to this question, but I was able to recover.  Essentially, since I dual boot with Windows, I am always presented with the option of "Prior ubuntu version recovery mode".

1. So I chose that
2. chose the latest version in following screen
3. Chose "dpkg" to fixbroken packages and let the installation continue clicking yes whenever prompted.

That ended up fixing the issue and I am able to use my computer now without re-installing.  So just to be clear, now I have 12.04 and since I didn't rollback, this is not really an answer for this question but I hope it is useful to someone facing the same situation

Comment: Perhaps retitle the question to be "How can I use prior version recovery mode?" or something so it can be found by the next person.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to roll back after such update. I'm afraid you need to reinstall 11.10 from scratch if you want it back.

Regarding mouse and keyboard problem - there is a chance that update killed your Xorg configuration somehow. I'd suggest you to take a look into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and other relevant places.

**UPDATE:**

There is a trick to save a package list and then bulk-install them on top of your fresh Ubuntu installation:

Save a list of installed packages:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > ubuntu-files
```

Now, when you've a clean installation of Ubuntu, install them back:

```
dpkg --set-selections < ubuntu-files
sudo dselect
```

Comment: @Andresj, the command which you gave me didn't work.  I got the message, dpkg: error: uknown option -g

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my message. It should be two minuses instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but a safe and wizarded downgrade is not possible. The best solution is backup everything and make a fresh install. You will find several topic around saying a downgrade is possible, but it's a manual operation that can be considered as equivalent as a fresh install after a backup.

If you could provide some logs, we could try to recover your installation and let you enjoy 12.04.

Comment: I didn't have to do this.  I am going to respond to my own question.  Please see below