# Ubuntu frozen post update on restart

Tags: updates, freeze

I just did today's software center updates for Ubuntu. On a required re-start, my computer is hanging at the shutdown screen that has "ubuntu" and the 5 dots underneat that change from white to orange. I've had this happen to me before in previous installations on older versions of Ubuntu, and when it has, I've been forced to do a hard shut down. This inevitably ends up corrupting some files and my OS either won't boot up correctly or I have sever sofware problems.

I haven't done the hard reset yet, and I am wondering if there's anything I can do to avoid doing the hard reset, and potentially saving my system from damage?

Comment: Also, I've just noticed my HDD LED light is on without blinking. Which worries me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: @Fabby is not reproducible http://askubuntu.com/a/143835/169736

Comment: @Braiam: I had a bunch of "freeze, freeze, freeze" questions in a row and my brain turned on the cruise control...  **Sorry!  :-(**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need to do anything. (This time) 
I did the hard re-start with great hesitation, and the system still boots and runs fine (fingers crossed).

Answer (score 0):

maybe my answer from https://askubuntu.com/a/140945/65352 will be useful to you:

Essentially, since I dual boot with Windows, I am always presented with the option of "Prior ubuntu version recovery mode".

1. So I chose that
2. chose the latest version in following screen
3. Chose "dpkg" to fixbroken packages and let the installation continue clicking yes whenever prompted.

That ended up fixing the issue and I am able to use my computer now without re-installing.  So just to be clear, now I have 12.04 and since I didn't rollback, this is not really an answer for this question but I hope it is useful to someone facing the same situation